# Defining a command with star argument to be used in pdf strings (e.g. via \section)

Tags: hyperref, pdf, expansion, starred-version

I want to define a command with an optional star argument and be able to use it inside pdf strings, e.g. via `\section`. With the MWE below, I get a `Token not allowed in a PDF string` warning and `\foo` is just removed.

I can't think of a safe expandable way to replace `\@ifstar` in order to do this. For my application, it would be okay to default to `\s@foo` inside a pdf string, but the `*` should be removed if present.

Is there any way to achieve this?

---

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
  \protected\def\foo{%
    \@ifstar\s@foo\@foo
  }
  \def\@foo#1{one #1 one}
  \def\s@foo#1{two #1 two}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{\foo{bar}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Depending on what you're actually trying to do, you can use `\texorpdfstring{regular tex}{inside pdf string}` from hyperref.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `xparse`, of course ;-)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \foo { s m }
  {%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
      {one #2 one}% Starred
      {two #2 two}% Non-starred
  }
\begin{document}
\section{\foo*{bar}}
\section{\foo{baz}}
\end{document}
```

The command that goes into the PDF bookmark has to be expandable, so you need an expandable mechanism to grab the optional `*`. Same goes for optional `[...]` arguments.

In the code above, the PDF bookmarks are `one bar one` and `two baz two`.